# Unlocking Bootloader of HTC One X on Windows 8.1 / Linux Ubuntu

Tags: windows, htc-one-x, htc, usb-drivers, bootloader-lock

How to unlock the bootloader of HTC One X on Windows 8.1? Since I want to install MIUI Rom.

When I install the latest version of "HTC Sync Manager", It shows me that the Windows 8.1 is not competible with this software. Therefore, the command `fastboot oem get_identifier_token` does not work because of the incompatible HTC Driver.

I am wondering whether I can unlock my HTC One X on my Linux Ubuntu? If yes, how to do it? Do I need to install HTC Driver on Linux Ubuntu?

**Thank you for your attention.**

Answer (score 2):

Linux is absolutely the best way to do this sort of things. This is a thread on xda about how to set the development environment on Linux Ubuntu in particular http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302780

Follow these steps and you'll have fastboot command set up to do the unlocking process. Plus you won't need any driver to let the system recognize the device.